# Airflow - Please check "executor" key in "core" section. Current value: "CeleryExecutor"

Tags: ubuntu, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install apache-airflow, so in airflow.cfg file changed the executor to Celery Executor but I am facing an error while doing airflow scheduler

[Please check "executor" key in "core" section. Current value: "CeleryExecutor"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZBgx.png)

Answer (score 0):

In airflow src code, you find this block:

```py
        try:
            executor_cls, import_source = cls.import_executor_cls(executor_name)
            log.debug("Loading executor %s from %s", executor_name, import_source.value)
        except ImportError as e:
            log.error(e)
            raise AirflowConfigException(
                f'The module/attribute could not be loaded. Please check "executor" key in "core" section. '
                f'Current value: "{executor_name}".'
            )
        log.info("Loaded executor: %s", executor_name)
```

So the real error is logged before `AirflowConfigException`, in your case it is `cannot import name 'BaseKeyValueStoreBackend' from 'celery.backends.base'`

Make sure you installed the additional celery dependencies when you installed airflow:

```bash
pip install 'apache-airflow[celery]'
```